# DC1 Can't See DC2 Nor Network Machines Can't See Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller

Using Windows Server 2008 R2

Found an issue with my Domain Controller 1. Setup is basic and the main domain controller is hosting AD and DNS. The secondary cannot find the primary.

```
dcgetdcname failed error 1355
```

As well as computers that are on the domain show the network as `Unidentified Network`

DC1 shows the correct domain it is connected to and working correctly. DCDIAG on the DC1 shows everything running correctly.  DC1 can also ping domain joined computers without a problem but cannot ping DC2.

DC2 also is the backup AD and DNS.

Googled everything under the sun but I can't get DC2 to see DC1 and the computers on the network to see the domain name correctly. I can't join computers to domain either as it says it cannot find the domain.

I can remote to the DC1 from any domain joined computer without a problem but I can't get to any fileshares on the DC1 either. Neither of the DCs are running NAT. This network is not internet joined.

Can anyone help?

EDIT1: NSLOOKUP cannot find the DNS servers. They time out.

EDIT2: DC1 and DC2 are using themselves as the DNS servers as they are marked as secondary's because they cannot reach each other to register each other as DNS servers for each other.

EDIT3: Update got DNS working only not sure how but now no computers on the network can reach the fileshares on the server itself. Firewalls are disabled and I can't find any issue with reaching them.

Comment: Are you running NT4? Because that's the last time there was ever a PDC/BDC. Where are you actually seeing the term "Primary Domain Controller" within your infrastructure?

Comment: @Wesley sorry I am calling it the "Primary Domain Controller". I am running Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: What do the DC's use for primary and secondary DNS? What do the domain clients use for primary and secondary DNS?

Comment: @joeqwerty Sorry what do you mean by use as primary? The 2 DCs are also running DNS so they are both the DC and the secondary and primary DC.

Comment: @JukEboX In the DNS settings for the server (the same settings as on a workstation) - which DNS is primary and secondary for each box?

Comment: @Dan Primary DNS is the Primary Domain Controller address and secondary as the Backup Domain controller.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PDC or BDC anymore, you should avoid using these terms as you will only confuse people (and yourself).

Comment: @JukEboX If one is a Primary Domain Controller, then it's not Windows Server 2008 R2. You may as well be calling a diesel truck "steam powered." The multi-master nature, and FSMO roles is completely contrary to the notion of PDC/BDC. There are no such things any more, and never will be again.

Comment: @Jukebox: Best practice dictates that each DC use it's partner DC for primary DNS, itself for secondary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS. Make sure that's how you have them configured. On the domain clients set the PDCe (the DC that holds the Primary Domain Controller Emulator FSMO role) as the primary DNS and the other DC as the secondary DNS. Then reboot your DC's one at a time and then reboot your clients. Then test again.

Comment: @joeqwerty ok let me check the DNS settings really quick and see what happens. Will be back to you in 2 seconds.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the input. That made the DCs both connect to the same domain finally. Now the remaining problem is that none of the computers on the network see the domain itself. All the computers say they are on an "unidentified network" . I have also done an ipconfig /flushdns and ipconfig /registerdns and still nothing. Ideas?

Comment: Are the client machines all joined to the domain?

Comment: @joeqwerty quick update again. Seems the BDC is using itself as the DNS as it can't reach the PDC as the primary for some stupid reason. This all seems to be stemming from the fact that the PDC can't be reached from the BDC and Visa Versa. They cannot ping each other and they cannot resolve each other as forward or reverse zones. Yes the clients are joined to the domain and the network location shows as unidentified network. If I try to join another machine to the domain it says it can't reach the domain to join it.

Comment: By not configuring DNS on **ALL** machines per best practice you are inadvertently influencing the problem which in turn is influencing the symptoms and the results of your tests (thereby altering the problem, it's symptoms and your test results). Configure the DNS settings on **ALL** machines to adhere to best practice and then perform your troubleshooting and testing.

Comment: After making the change to the DNS the original issue still occurs. Both DCs can't talk to each other and the network nodes say they are still on an unidentified network.

Comment: Added Edit to question.

Comment: Are these virtual machines?

Comment: @Davidw Negative. All hardware. Also Group policies are not coming down from the DC.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you have routing or numbering issues.  Check the IP addresses of the servers and ensure that they are getting them from DHCP.  If the DCs are not on the same subnet, there needs to be a router in between them (if only a router on a stick).  Check that they can actually ping one another.  Check that firewalls, local and network, are not restricting necessary traffic like RPC and DNS.

From what you've posted, it really just looks like DC2 doesn't have a working network connection or lacks a route to and from DC1.

Comment: There is no DHCP. Everything is static. They are all on the same network with no subnets. Nodes can ping each other and the DCs. Oddly enough DC1 can't ping DC2 by name but it can by address. DNS and RPC are being allowed through firewall correctly on both DCs.